# Jquery ajax call is not working in php

Tags: php, jquery

### I am trying to get the values from array and assign the data in to form fields. Below is the code. Pls share your feedback

### Profile Form:

The below function will execute when user select/change the values in drop down.

```
<script type ="text/javascript" >
function LoadResdetails()
{

    $resid = document.getElementById("cmbActiveRes").value; 
    document.getElementById("cmbActiveRes").addEventListener('click', stopDefAction, false);
    document.getElementById("cmbActiveRes").addEventListener('change', stopDefAction, false);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "admnewprofile.php",        
        data: {functionName: "LoadResDetailsByID",param: "14"},
        error:function(request,error)
        {
            console.log(error);
        },
        success:function(data) {            
            console.log("sucess")
            console.log(data.UserID); //tried both..
            console.log(data['UserID);

        }
    });
}
function stopDefAction(evt) {   
    evt.preventDefault();
}
```

### END OF THE FILE.

I am not even getting the functioname value while echo..

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
{

    echo $_GET["functionName"];

    if (isset($_GET["functionName"]) && !empty($_GET["functionName"]))
    {
        echo $_GET["functionName"];
        //Checks if action value exists
        $action = $_GET["functionName"];
        echo "action name.$action.";
        switch($action)
        {
        case "LoadResDetailsByID": LoadResDetailsByID($_GET["param"]);
        break;
        }
    }

    function LoadResDetailsByID($ResID)
    {
        echo $ResID;

        if($ResID > 0)
        {
        try {       
            $objprofile = new admuserprofile();
            $RetDatas = $objprofile->LoadSelectedResourceDetails($ResID);           
        }
        catch (ErrorException $e)
        {
            echo "error".$e->getMessage();
        }
        echo json_encode($RetDatas);

        }       
    }
}
```

## class file

This class file contains all the methods.

```
class admuserprofile
{

    public function LoadSelectedResourceDetails($ResID)
    {
        $sql = "sp_GetLoadResourceDetailsByID";
        $rowsets = array();
        try
        {   
            $objCon = new connections();            
            $dbLink = $objCon->connectDB();         
            $result = $objCon->c_mysqli_call($dbLink, $sql,"'$ResID'");             
             if($result)
            {
                foreach($result as $_row)
                {
                    /* $rowsets = $_row;             */
                    $rowsets['UserID'] = $_row['UserID']; 
                    $rowsets['FirstName'] = $_row['FirstName'];
                    $rowsets['MI'] = $_row['MI'];
                    $rowsets['LastName'] = $_row['LastName'];                   
                    $rowsets['Department'] = $_row['Department'];
                    $rowsets['Locations'] = $_row['Locations'];
                    $rowsets['EmailID'] = $_row['EmailID'];
                }
            }
            mysqli_close();
            unset($dbLink);
            unset($result);
            unset($objCon);

        }       
        catch (Exception $error)
        {
            mysqli_close();
            echo "Issue in executing an query";
        }               
        echo json_encode($rowsets); 
        /* return $rowsets; */

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checkd developer's console? Are there any error messages?

Comment: No errors. Below is the console output.

Comment: "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/UATeng/jquery-ui-1.11.2.custom/images/ui-bg_glass_45_0078ae_1x400.png"
ui-bg_g...400.png
GET http://localhost/UATeng/admnewprofile.php?functionName=LoadResDetailsByID&param=14
 
200 OK
  4ms 
jquery-....min.js (line 4)
sucess
admnewprofile.php (line 124)
undefined                    --- This is due to the data was empty
admnewprofile.php (line 125)

Comment: GET http://localhost/UATeng/admnewprofile.php?functionName=LoadResDetailsByID&param=14
 
200 OK 4ms 
jquery-....min.js (line 4)
sucess
admnewprofile.php (line 124)
undefined
admnewprofile.php (line 125)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not enter..., try:

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
die();
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
{
```

Comment: echo print as GET. The console output remains same.

Comment: what happen if you remove data: {functionName: "LoadResDetailsByID",param: "14"}, and add the next to url: "admnewprofile.php?functionName=LoadResDetailsByID&param=14"

Comment: Hi I got a solution. There is some issue in my model. I fixed that issue and it's working fine now.